# Youtube AutoPlay in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, youtube, webbrowser-control, autoplay

I recently doing a simple education school project on Visual Studio, which I can open a text file and watch all the youtube videos I have saved as links. The main program is done, now I just have to deal with this Youtube AutoPlay thing that I can't fix.

It's a webbrowser and after I import, the combobox will show the links. I can then play "start" to navigate to the youtube links one after another like a playlist. Even though it brings me to the page but it just don't autoplay. I need to manual click to start playing. I want it to be automatic.

?autoplay=1 or &autoplay=1 is not working. Maybe a auto click code or script can help me solve the issue.

Comment: autoplay=1 should work , but you'll need a /v/ as well , i.e. if you're normal link is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ik8yt8yUGs then change it to :  http://www.youtube.com/v/7ik8yt8yUGs&autoplay=1

Answer (score 0):

**autoplay=1** should work , but you'll need a **/v/** as well , i.e:

If you're normal link is:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=7ik8yt8yUGs
```

then change it to :

```
youtube.com/v/7ik8yt8yUGs&autoplay=1
```